# Anyone know how the Abp.io roles works ? because I want to create my own roles . and assign it as default roles

Tags: solution, abp

How the Roles works in Abp.Io framework , like default it comes with admin role and with some permission same way I want to create my own role and assign some permission for that role , through the code. Anyone have any idea ? HELP

The Documents didn't worked for me , May be I didn't understood the Doc. Anyone have any solution ? that might work ?

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own roles via seeds or programmatically.

1. and put the the flag default true so it will assign this roled to
   the new user on creating.
2. you can listen on event creating on class Identity user in app service you can implement this interface and write ILocalEventHandler<EntityDeletedEventData<Volo.Abp.Identity.IdentityUser>>

Comment: Thank you for response , But can you provide some Github links !. So I can understand it easily ,Because I am new to abp.io